# R glmertree: right variables for components? limit patitioning layers? adjust plot? result interpretion?

Tags: r, classification, multiple-regression, partitioning

As a very beginner user, I have the following questions during my testing:

**1. What are the suitable variables in the dataset for each of the components on the right side of the below tree formula?**

> ```
> response ~ node-specific predictors | global predictors | partitioning variables
> ```

(cited from: https://doi.org/10.1080/10503307.2020.1785037)

**2. can stop the partitioning at some levels? I do not want a very big and detail tree.**

**3. How to adjust the plot for such a big tree? e.g. make it wider?**

**4. How to interpret the results?**

---

**Data:**

Variable definitions:

1. nd_clust,nd_deg,nd_const,nd_bet_cen,nd_cl_cen,nd_ei_cen
   these are measures for individual social network properties, such as clustering coefficient, degree,constraint coefficient, centralities
2. filename : the file the individual works on
3. fileteamsize: one file may have multiple individuals work on, these measures how big is the team in terms of file
4. Project_name: the project the individual belongs to
5. pj_bet_cen,pj_clo_cen,pj_ei_cen, pj_deg_cen,pj_clust,pj_trans:
   these are measures of the project's social network structure, such as degree of closure and centralization.
6. join_dur_sec: the last time the individual work on the files in the project - the first time the individual work on the files in the project . This is about how long the individual joined the project.
7. fileteamlevel: computed based on fileteamsize variable.
   fileteamsize == 1:"solo worker", == 2:"dyadic", == 3:"tradic",4 - 10: "group", >= 11:"crowd"

```
'data.frame':   16655 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ names        : chr  "xxx@yyy.com" "xxx@yyy.com" "xxx@yyy.com" "xxx@yyy.com" ...
 $ productivity: num  1521 1521 1521 1521 1521 ...
 $ nd_clust     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ nd_deg       : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ nd_const     : num  0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 ...
 $ nd_bet_cen   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nd_cl_cen    : num  0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 ...
 $ nd_ei_cen    : num  0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 ...
 $ filename     : Factor w/ 2740 levels ".gitignore",".idea/.name",..: 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 ...
 $ fileteamsize : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Project_name : Factor w/ 2 levels "github.android",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pj_bet_cen   : num  0.000245 0.000245 0.000245 0.000245 0.000245 ...
 $ pj_clo_cen   : num  1.09 1.09 1.09 1.09 1.09 ...
 $ pj_ei_cen    : num  0.777 0.777 0.777 0.777 0.777 ...
 $ pj_deg_cen   : num  0.821 0.821 0.821 0.821 0.821 ...
 $ pj_clust     : num  0.778 0.778 0.778 0.778 0.778 ...
 $ pj_trans     : num  0.313 0.313 0.313 0.313 0.313 ...
 $ join_dur_sec : num  40097055 40097055 40097055 40097055 40097055 ...
 $ fileteamlevel: Factor w/ 5 levels "crowd","dyadic",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

**Test tree**

```
tree1 <- lmertree(prod_node_avg ~ 1 | fileteamlevel | nd_clust + join_dur_sec  , data = data)
plot(tree1)
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Choosing partitioning variables (i.e., variable for the right-most part of the formula)

Generally, these are properties that are possibly predictive of the response variable. These may in your example be individual social network properties, or the project's social network structure properties.

### Limiting tree size

To limit tree size, there are several options. The default approach is to stop splitting only when no significant instability is found of the fixed-effects parameters (the fixed intercept, in your model) in any of the nodes, with respect to any of the partitioning variables. With large sample sizes, this might yield a large tree, as in your dataset. This tree might predict well, but interpretability is obviously difficult. To better balance accuracy and interpretability, you can do the following:

- Increase `minsize`, the minimum number of observations that a node should contain. It defaults to 10 times the number of parameters to be estimated (see also `?mob_control`, which describes many of the arguments that can be passed functions `(g)lmertree` trough the ellipsis `...`. You have 1 parameter in each terminal node, so `minsize` equals 10. You could use cross validation to choose an optimal value, or more subject-matter considerations. E.g., if you think subgroups of 250 yield stable results, because this is large enough for a subgroup to generalize well and to be of practical use, then you specify `minsize = 250` in the call to `(g)lmertree`. Considering your sample size of $N>16,000$, you might want to consider an even larger value for `minsize`.
- Decrease `maxdepth`. This parameter has a similar, but not the same, effect as `minsize`. It can be helpful in a similar manner as `minsize` discussed above.  Here, your prior belief on the possible interaction depth might also come into play. But note that tree depth is not the same as interaction depth; the larger the tree depth, the higher the order of interactions that *can* be captured by the tree. You could also use cross validation to choose an optimal value.
- Decrease `alpha`, the significance level used to decide when to stop splitting. It defaults to .05, lower values will yield a stricter stopping criterion and likely a smaller tree. Although your plot indicates that even for the lower splits, $\alpha$ values are $<.001$, so you'll likely need quite small values. I also see some splits with $\alpha = .01$, though, so specifying e.g., $alpha = .0001$ might be useful. You could also use cross validation to choose an optimal value.

### Improving plots

The first go-to for improving readability is `cex`, which controls the size of plotting symbols, which default to 1. You can pass this argument to the `...` of the `plot` method of `(g)lmertree`. These arguments will be passed to `plot.modelparty`, also see `partykit::plot.modelparty`.

In your example:

```
plot(tree1, gp = gpar(cex = .5))
```

### Interpretation

The tree you plotted does not have the right amount of detail yet, so cannot say anything about that. The second plot shows the estimated random effects (intercepts, in your case) for each of the levels of `fileteamlevel`. These means have been estimated using all observations in the dataset, and indicate a higher level of `prod_node_avg` for `tradic` observations, and a lower level of `prod_node_avg` for `crowd`. You can also extract these as numeric values by typing `ranef(tree1)`.

Note that this gives one of the two means that apply to each observation in your dataset. The other mean is given by the terminal node they are part of:

If the nodes in the plot would be better visible, they would show a boxplot of observed values for observations within that terminal node. Because these are observed values, they might not completely show the same pattern as the estimated effects, which account for `fileteamlevel`; the observed distributions plotted do not. For numerical results, run `coef(tree1)`, this gives you the estimated fixed-effects means for each of the selected subgroups; these account for `fileteamlevel`.